# Layers between docker builds can't be shared

Tags: docker, docker-layer

I want to reuse the layers from a docker image on two different machines in the following way:

- Build image (1)
- Push image to registry (1)
- Pull image from registry (2)
- Build same docker image and reuse layers from pulled image (2)

Therefore,

**Machine 1**:

I build this following image:

```
FROM node:13-slim

COPY package.json package.json
```

- Build this image with the following command: `docker build . -t <registry>/test-docker-image:latest`
- Push the image to a registry: `docker push <registry>/test-docker-image:latest`

**Machine 2**

- Pull the image from the registry: `docker pull <registry>/test-docker-image:latest`

If I run `docker build .` on this machine the layers are not reused from the pulled image.

Is there a way to reuse the layers from the pulled image in the `docker build`?

**Similar issue**:

There is the following thread on GitHub that describes something similar, but this describes the issue between sharing layers between `docker build` and `docker-compose build`. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/883

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trust the layers of a pulled image that wasn't built locally, you need `-cache-from`, e.g.:

```
docker build --cache-from=<registry>/test-docker-image:latest -t newimg:latest .
```

Docker won't trust pulled images by default to avoid a malicious image that claims to provide layers for an image you may build while actually including malicious content in that layer.

For more details on args to `docker build`, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/